# Django. Objects from several models, how to correct display url?

Tags: django

I have two models. I do filtering of objects by these models and display them in a template.
Everything works fine, but an error occurs with url.

my **urls.py**

```
path('objects_model_A/<int:objects_A_id>', views.objects_A, name='objects_model_A'),
path('objects_model_B/<int:objects_B_id>', views.objects_B, name='objects_model_B'),
```

my **views.py**

```
def index(request):
    objects_A = objects_A.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
    objects_B = objects_B.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
    queryset_list = list(chain(objects_A, objects_B))
    context = {'queryset_list': queryset_list}
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', context)

def objects_A(request, objects_A_id):
    objects_A = get_object_or_404(objects_a, pk=objects_A_id)
    context = {
        'objects_A': objects_A
    }
    return render(request, 'templates/objects_A.html', context)

def objects_B(request, objects_B_id):
    objects_B = get_object_or_404(objects_b, pk=objects_B_id)
    context = {
        'objects_A': objects_A
    }
    return render(request, 'templates/objects_B.html', context)
```

my **template.html**

```
{% if queryset_list %}
    {% for listing in queryset_list %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'objects_model_A' listing.id %}">Link
                </a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Objects from different models are collected, have an appropriate data set, but url are wrong.

The object with **model_A**, url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/objects_A/1
```

An object with **model_B**, url too:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/objects_A/1
```

I understand the error in the template. Line `<a href="{% url 'objects_model_A' listing.id %}`.

How to draw up URLs correctly so that objects from different models in the chain are displayed correctly. For **object A** was url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/objects_A/1
```

For **object B** was url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/objects_B/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One often specifies a canonical URL at the model level with a [**`get_absolute_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url). You can thus implement this like:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class objects_A(models.Model):

    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('objects_model_A', kwargs={'objects_A_id': self.pk})

class objects_B(models.Model):

    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('objects_model_B', kwargs={'objects_B_id': self.pk})
```

In your template, you can then use:

```
{% for listing in queryset_list %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div>
            <a href="{{ listing.get_absolute_url }}">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Django has some tooling that takes `get_absolute_url` into account. For example you can pass a model object with a `get_absolute_url` method to a [**`redirect(..)`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), and Django will then redirect to the `get_absolute_url()` result of that object.

Comment: **Willem Van Onsem**, Hello! This is exclusively what I need !! Thanks, it works great!